# ¿Por qué no recarga los datos cuando me desplazo hacia abajo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Lo que estoy haciendo es un scroll infinito con jQuey, AJAX y PHP, cuando tiene que recargar más datos, en vez de recargarlos cuando hago scroll hacia abajo, lo que me hace es que tenga que volver al top de la página para que se recarguen más datos, que tengo que cambiar en mi código para que se recargue cuando esta casi al bottom de la página? Gracias de antemano!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var start = 0;
            var limit = 5;
            var reachedMax = false;

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
                getData();
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
           getData();
        });

        function getData() {
            if (reachedMax)
                return;

            $.ajax({
               url: 'publicaciones.php',
               method: 'POST',
               dataType: 'text',
               data: {
                   getData: 1,
                   start: start,
                   limit: limit
               },
               success: function(response) {
                    if (response == "reachedMax")
                        reachedMax = true;
                    else {
                        start += limit;
                        $(".results").append(response);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include ('../conexion.php');

    if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
    {
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_SESSION['id']);

        $infouser = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id");  
        $use = mysqli_fetch_array($infouser);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['getData']))
    {   
        $start = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['start']);
        $limit = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['limit']);

        $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM publicaciones ORDER BY id_pub DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");   

        if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta) > 0)
        {   
            while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
?>
                <div class="card mt-3 border-0 rounded-0">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <div class="img-user rounded-circle">
                                    <img class="img-fluid-pub" src="../avatars/<?php echo $use['avatar']; ?>" alt="User Image">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <h3 class="text-muted" onclick="location.href='perfil.php?id=<?php echo $use['id']; ?>';"><?php echo $use['usuario']; ?></h3><h3>Seguir</h3>
                                <p><?php echo $data['fecha']; ?></p>
                                <p><?php echo $data['titulo']; ?> Me gusta</p>
                                <p id="descripcion"><?php echo $data['descripcion']; ?></p>
                                <p class="leermas" onclick="leerMas(this);">Leer más...</p>             
                                <video controls>
                                    <source src="../anadir-publicacion/publicaciones/<?php echo $data['video']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                                    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                                </video>
                                <p>Kcal: <?php echo $data['kcal']; ?> CarbHid: <?php echo $data['carbohidratos']; ?> Prot: <?php echo $data['proteinas']; ?> Gras: <?php echo $data['grasas']; ?> Tiempo: <?php echo $data['tiempo']; ?>m Personas: <?php echo $data['personas']; ?> Dinero aprox: <?php echo $data['precio']; ?>€ Categoría: <?php echo $data['categoria']; ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<?php                   
            }
        }
        else 
            exit('reachedMax');
    }   
?>
```

Comment: debes publicar un ejemplo para poder ayudarte, por el momento prueba comentar el `if` (que está dentro del `.scroll`) con el fin de determinar si la función `getData()` es funcional

Comment: si que es funcional, si lo comento no me carga nada, se que es por el .scrollTop, pero el problema es que no existe .scrollBottom y no se como hacerlo

Comment: `getData()` funciona bien?

Comment: si, si quito el if y hago el scroll hacia arriba para que me cargue, no me carga nada, si está el getdata si que me carga los datos, pero lo que necesito es que me los cargue cuando hace scroll hacia abajo no hacia arriba

Comment: remplaza `success: function(response) {` por `success: function(response) {console.log(response)` y publica el contenido de **response**

Comment: response is not defined

Comment: revisa `publicaciones.php` no esta retornando el valor deseado

Comment: He subido el php arriba.